# wxpython textctrl doesn't write when bound

Tags: wxpython, bind, textctrl

I have been working on a simple textctrl project to get more acquainted with wxpython and I have hit a small road block. I am making a simple code editor, and I am currently working on the syntax highlighting. Everything works fine except because I have my textctrl bound to an event:

```
self.status_area.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.onKeyPress)
```

and I have code in that definition:

```
def onKeyPress (self, event):
    Line = self.status_area.GetValue()
```

It will no longer allow the user to type in any letters. I am able to delete and create a new line without any problem, but if I type "hello" nothing will show up. When debugging my code I know its running through onKeyPress() and the code inside and if I change the code to:

```
def onKeyPress (self, event):
    event.Skip()
```

it will work fine. I tried to recode the normal text editor workings into the onKeyPress() but it began to get too bulky. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That fixed the problem I had, thank you so much. This is a really good forum. I didn't need to add the event.skip() though.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it fixed your problem. You can do that by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer.

Comment: what fixed the problem, i cant see anything :(

Answer (score 2):

Try `EVT_TEXT` rather than `EVT_CHAR`.  In my solution, I added it AFTER `event.Skip()`

Comment: It doesn't matter where you call `event.Skip()` in an event handler, as long as you call it if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

to creat textctrl

```
self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel_1, -1, "some thing", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_RICH2 )
```

to bind

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.ON_Write, self.text_ctrl)
```

now the definition:

```
def ON_Write(self, event):
   line = self.text_ctrl.Value
```